# SQL to select records with a date greater than 40 days prior to start of month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a field in my table that holds a date and is in Datetime format.

I wish to select all records where the date in that field is greater than the date that is 40 days prior to the 1st of the current month.

Struggling to come up with the correct T-SQL syntax to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression gives you the date you are looking for:

```
DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(d, GETDATE()) + 1 - 40, GETDATE())
```

Comment: +1. `DAY(...)` (instead of `DATEPART(d, ...)`) is more concise, though, as is mere subtracting versus `DATEADD()`.

Comment: Which part of this expression accounts for starting the count-back from the first of the current month?

Answer (score 3):

Will this work

```
 select @urdatecolumn > (getdate()- (DAY(getdate()) + 40-1))
```

Comment: Your solution is most concise, only slightly incorrect. You need too subtract one day less, i.e. it should be something like `... + 40 - 1))`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
where dt_blah > DATEADD(d,-40,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, dateadd(dd, 6 - datepart(day, dt_blah), dt_blah)), 0)
```